# ESP32 emulator for use when coding in C/C++

Tags: emulator

A friend who wants to get into ESP32 just asked me if there is an emulator.

This had never even occurred to me, as they are so cheap, that I just keep buying them by the handful. However, I can see use is testing, if I want to simulate a fault, or return a certain value (e.g for temperature or battery charge).

A quick DuckDuckGo found [this](https://pypi.org/project/esp32-machine-emulator/), which is an emulator for ADaFruit's MicroPython (but not stock, official Python).

Is there a similar ESP32 emulator for those who code in C/C++ ?  Any operating system / price will be considered, as I don't expect much in the way of reply.

Comment: I have found this but have not tried it personally. https://github.com/mireq/esp32-simulator